# List name and numbers between two values

Tags: vba, excel

I have been googling a lot and I couldnt make this one work in any way.

I have a table of three columns (Name, Value1, Value2) with lots of names.
I need a vba to list all numbers between value 1&2 including them and their respective names.

For example for row A, 3000, 3003 make rows A, 3000; A, 3001; A, 3002; A, 3003 and then continue on the next name and split that name's range into individual numbers.

Is this even possible?

Thank you so much.

Comment: are you trying to expand the existing table, or create a new one? If the latter, then it seems to be a pretty simple vba task

Comment: Both are fine. I seem to be just not good enough to do it.

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: Have you looked into Do Loops?

Comment: Have you tried any code at all that we can build on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote one based on an array to collect then transfer the values.

```
Sub expandValues()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        .Cells(1, "E").Resize(1, 2) = Array("Name", "Value")

        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ReDim arr(.Cells(i, "B").Value2 To .Cells(i, "C").Value2, 1 To 2)
            For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                arr(j, 1) = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
                arr(j, 2) = j
            Next j
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0). _
              Resize(UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

**[Addendum:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166200/list-name-and-numbers-between-two-values/51166693#51166693)**

Here is yours with an outer loop to process through the rows.

```
Sub FillIN()
    Dim stri As Long, endi As Long
    Dim nm As string, i as long, j as long

    with workSheets(1)
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            nm = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            strti = .Cells(i, "B").Value
            endi = .Cells(i, "C").Value

            For j= strti To endi
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = nm
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = j
            Next j
        next i
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: Much better idea +1

Comment: I love your solution Jeeped. And it starts but then throws an error: Out of memory. It gives maybe a quarter values thought the process. So the solution is nice and elegant but it seems that the list is too long. Is it possible to tweak the other one with outer loop? Maybe that will work.

Comment: I love your solution Jeeped. And it starts but then throws an error: Out of memory. It gives maybe a quarter values thought the process. So the solution is nice and elegant but it seems that the list is too long. Is it possible to tweak the other one with outer loop? Maybe that will work.

Comment: Just how large do Value1 and value2 get?

Comment: Max Value 9800. And the difference between Value 1 & 2 is between 2-50ish. But there was around 900 rows of data with Value 1 & 2. With QHars solution I got 18k pairs of Name & Value. Your solution is perfect Jepped. I just failed to mention the size because I didnt think it would make a problem. Apparently for array it could be.

Comment: I've added an outer loop to your code in an addendum above.

Comment: tbh, it shouldn't have blown up with those numbers but it did so back to the drawing board.

Comment: Thank you Jepeed!

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ListLines()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, y As Long, rowCounter As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet: rowCounter = 1
    With ws
        For i = 2 To GetLastRow(ws, 1)
            For y = .Cells(i, 2) To .Cells(i, 3)
                .Cells(rowCounter, 5) = .Cells(i, 1)
                .Cells(rowCounter, 6) = y
                 rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            Next y
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal columNum As Long) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: QHarr, this is great. Jeppeds solution is prettier and both work but it was my fault that I didnt state how long is the list so his runs out of memory.

Comment: Jeeped's answer, as usual, is first rate. Mine is less efficient by a mile (+ a lot)  but does show you how to use a Loop which was my intention. :-)

Comment: Jepped is amazing. Super fast and super creative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far. And it semi works. I need to make it jump on the next line ( it just repeats the first one forever ) and make it stop when done. 
I havent been able to make it add +1 on the row portion of (Row, Column) in starti and endi and Name i after it is done with first row range. Mine also runs indefinitely so I also miss a stop once done.

```
Sub FillIN()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stri As Long, endi As Long
Dim Name As Variant

Set ws = Sheets(1)
Name = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value
strti = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value
endi = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value

For i = strti To endi
ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = i
ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Name
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It ssems you just need another outer loop to go through the cells row by row.